# Autotools: creating a static library from differently compiled sources

Tags: autotools, static-linking, automake, libtool, unix-ar

I am trying to build a static library from several sources. The problem is that for some sources I have to use different `CFLAGS`.

In the beginning I thought about creating several `noinst_LIBRARIES` and finally combine them to one in `lib_LIBRARIES` using `LIBADD`. This approach fails because there is no way to combine static libraries using `ar` without extracting them.

This is how my `Makefile.am` currently looks:

```
noinst_LIBRARIES = lib1.a lib2.a
lib_LIBRARIES = final.a

final_a_CFLAGS = -Werror
final_a_SOURCES = mainlib/src.c
final_a_LIBADD = lib1.a lib2.a

lib1_a_CFLAGS = -O0
lib1_a_SOURCES = lib1/src11.c lib1/src12.c

lib2_a_CFLAGS = -O3
lib2_a_SOURCES = lib2/src21.c
```

I have already thought about substituting `AR` with an `ar` wrapper that will first extract the libraries and then combine them in the `final.a`. But I do not like this approach, so is there a correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want convenience libraries.  They are documented in the manual.